# more than one parameter in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument, addhandler

If I have just a single command in my .htaccess file it works fine.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

As soon as I add anything else on a new line i.e.

```
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .html .htm .ssi .inc
```

I get Server error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Check your error logs, they'll tell you exactly what's wrong

Comment: Do you know which one, I should be looking at?